# How to maintain your development website vs. production website in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

In a wordpress installation we want to have our main site, and a staging site separated and different. Where in the admin interface you separate your staging area?

Let's say:

for production you will have:  http://www.yourdomain.com/

but for staging we want to have: http://www.yourdomain.com/staging

Staging is the website that will be in production next.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just found the following post in another stackexchange site, please moderators evaluate if this is necessary to close and move, or if the answers here are relevant to this community.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Wordpress 3.0+ you might be able to create a [network of sites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) or [install multiple sites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs) with an older version of Wordpress.  The catch is I don't know of an easy way of moving the staging to production.  I'm not entirely sure that will do what you want, but you may want to look into it.

Personally I'd think you'd probably be better off keeping your staging and production sites on 2 different servers and just do a copy over when you move to production.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid having two separate servers because of the cost implication, but it sounds that the other option will be more complicated.

Comment: You don't need to host it on different servers. You might as well use a password protected subdomain (i.e. _dev.mydomain.com_) or subdirectory (i.e. _mydomain.com/dev/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any instant, simple answers, but have you seen this article in the Wordpress support forum? It has some informed discussion and at-least partial solutions:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/one-wpseveral-servers

Answer (score -2):

If your staging site doesn't need any database modification, or custom forms/widgets for the backend, you can create a new theme, and test it in the preview mode. When done, you can switch the theme to the new one!

Comment: Hi Keatch, that sounds good for smaller changes or theme changes.  Right now our production view is a coming soon page, and the staging is the actual website.  So there will be a lot of changes, and people to view the staging site.  I would expect that WordPress has a solution for this already, I am sure I am not the only one with the situation. thanks,